# Adding an option to the right click menu for a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know if it's possible to add to the mouse right click menu in Chrome another option which would communicate with an extension?

I mean, after installing an extension, another option would appear in the mouse's right click menu which will send to a listener opened by the extension the data.

Comment: sorry found it
http://superuser.com/questions/179347/can-i-add-right-click-options-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
rightClickHandler = function(){
  //Do your stuff over that selected context menu
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Bitly Short Link",
  contexts:["link","selection"],  // ContextType
  onclick: rightClickHandler // A callback function
});
```

In manifest.json, have this permission:

```
{ "permissions": ["...", "contextMenus"], }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Add id it's madatory now