# On right click chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that allows to search via image, so what want to do is when the user right clicks on an image an opening called "search with xyz" should appear. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Empty Background.js

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/)

Comment: It already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903794/adding-an-option-to-the-right-click-menu-for-a-chrome-extension, sorry community