# Adding custom option in the right click menu through chromium Chrome Session C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, right-click

I want to create my own option in the context menu that appears on right clicking anywhere on the chrome browser.

I tried looking into solutions and this one so far seems to have the answer to my problem:
[Adding an option to the right click menu for a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903794/adding-an-option-to-the-right-click-menu-for-a-chrome-extension?rq=1)
However, I don't understand how to create the manifest file / use it with C# ChromeDriver ? (Chromium)

Another code I found on another similar problem which might be helpful
[Chrome Extension add option to right click context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937098/20677056)

Comment: If any one can provide any help it would be really great, this is super urgent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible currently in chrome, As far as my search went to.
However it is possible to implement whatever functionality was needed by other means..